# Parser Error Message: Could not load type "ContextModule"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have just started to learn asp.net MVC3 and i run into this problem:

[image: error message]

I'm using visual studio 2010, and there were no Errors during build, only when i try to run application. 
I'm searching for an answer on Google but with no success.
Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

**EDIT-ContextModule code:**

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace testbaza.Models
{
    public class ContextModule : IHttpModule
    {

        internal const string CONTEXT_KEY = "datacontext";

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PostRequestHandlerExecute);
            context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
        }

        private void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session[CONTEXT_KEY] = new EntitiesModel();
            }
        }

        private void context_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommitTransactions();

            DisposeContext();

            ClearSession();

        }

        private void CommitTransactions()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            EntitiesModel dbContext =
                HttpContext.Current.Session[CONTEXT_KEY] as EntitiesModel;
            if (dbContext != null)
            {

                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void DisposeContext()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            EntitiesModel dbContext =
                HttpContext.Current.Session[CONTEXT_KEY] as EntitiesModel;
            if (dbContext != null)
            {

                dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void ClearSession()
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(CONTEXT_KEY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have attached a HTTP module that cannot be found. How have you created the project? 
The module can be removed in web.config.

**EDIT**
You need to change:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ContextModule" type="testbaza.ContextModule, testbaza" />
</httpModules>
```

to

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ContextModule" type="testbaza.Models.ContextModule, testbaza" />
</httpModules>
```

Notice the changed namespace.

Comment: i have created module and project as shown in this video http://tv.telerik.com/watch/orm/building-a-mvc-3-application-database-first-with-openaccess-creating-model

Comment: @user1598696 Could you post the source code for ContextModule? Just to be able to check namespace, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should remove the `, testbaza` part from your `add` tag.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```